# Rollback on Error in PostInst Script in Debian Installer

Tags: bash, installation, rollback, deb, post-install

For a Debian installer script, if there is an error within the postinst script or the user uses Ctrl+C to kill the process, is it possible to have the entire install be rolled back? It looks like even if I return a non zero exit code, it still leaves the program installed.

Comment: `postinst` means *after* installation. You'd need to fail earlier in the process.

Comment: So there is no real way to do the rollback then, unless I do it earlier? Is it possible to execute a uninstall script within postinst, if I can't use the deb installer to handle it myself?

Comment: I'm not going to say it's impossible, but this does not sit well with the `dpkg` model. I think something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79050/can-i-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade-if-something-goes-wrong would be required to restore the earlier system state to cover all bases (installation was an upgrade vs a first install; installation pulled in new dependencies, etc). Maybe see also https://people.debian.org/~srivasta/MaintainerScripts.html though it does not actually cover this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Well, it's probably *possible*, because the `postinst` runs as root and can do all sorts of tricky stuff to subvert the system. But `dpkg` tries to protect against this as much as possible using locks, because maintainer scripts should not ever change the "desired" status of packages.

I haven't verified this, but I would guess that if you cancel a `postinst` script with Ctrl+C, it counts as a `postinst` failure, and the package is marked as being in the `half-configured` state. So, it's not left fully-installed, exactly, but yeah, it might be hard for the user to tell the difference.

So, some potential solutions for you:

1. If your package provides a service, you could have a flag (*e.g.*, a file in some place like `/var/lib/$yourpackage`) which is set only when the package is fully installed (at the end of the `postinst`). The service would check for this flag on startup, and if it's not present, the service would not start, and might even print a warning message about not being fully installed. This solution would be similar in some respects to having the package totally uninstalled. Remember to unset the flag or remove the file at in the `prerm` and at the beginning of the `postinst` (in case a Ctrl+C occurs during an upgrade instead of on the first install).
2. You could catch the Ctrl+C (`SIGINT`) in the `postinst`, and print a message saying something like "`This package will be left in the Failed-Config state. To remove it entirely, run (dpkg -P/apt purge/whatever). To attempt to complete installation, run dpkg --configure -a.`" (Then exit the `postinst` with a nonzero exit code, so that dpkg knows about the failure.)
3. If you are in a position to do this, make your users more aware of when they have brokenly-installed packages, so they can make the decisions about reinstalling or removing quickly.
4. You could take whatever thing in your `postinst` is most likely to be Ctrl+C'd, and move it to the `preinst`. If the `preinst` fails, then `dpkg` will call the `postrm` with the `abort-install` action. The `postrm` is expected to clean up anything that the `preinst` already did. If the `postrm` succeeds, then the package is left cleanly and entirely uninstalled. Of course, if this step of the `postinst` needs the files from your package to be unpacked and present, this isn't really an option.